# Use MSBuild macro like $(ProjectDir) in C# code

Tags: c#, msbuild

Can I use MSBuild variables so that they are resolved in my code? I am thinking of a piece of code that requires the `$(ProjectDir)`, because it will never be moved (it is a unit test project).

An example:

```
public class MyTestDataPath
{
    public void GetTestData()
    {
        return SOME_COMPILE_TIME_PROJECT_DIR_MACRO + "\\test-data"; // Should resolve via $(ProjectDir) during compile time.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. But not directly in your code. You could define a prebuild action in your project properties:

```
echo $(ProjectDir) > "$(ProjectDir)\Resources\ProjDir.txt"
```

Then you can add the file projdir.txt as a resource in your project properties and reference the content in your code with:

```
var dir = Resources.ProjDir
```

But I would simply copy the test data in your postbuild action into the output directory and use reflection to get it at runtime (binaries and test data are now portable to other developers).

Comment: Putting it in the resources is a nice idea. Didn't think of that one before.

Comment: I hope that answer is good enough for you and it worked. I just thought about another workaround: you could write `var dir = "__PROJDIR__"` and in the prebuild step you could search & replace `__PROJDIR__` with `$(ProjectDir)`.

Comment: But it would always come to a pre-build step. That's something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Why would you like to avoid the prebuild step?

Comment: Because I have over 100 csproj files that will need the same code. There still isn't something like a pre-build step solution wide. Except for a .bat file of course. But then I would still have to add the bat file to all 100 projects.

Comment: A projectfile is a simple XML file. You could find & replace over all .csproj / .vcxproj and modify / append a new / existing post build step with something like `<PropertyGroup>
 <PostBuildEvent>echo $(ProjectDir) > "$(ProjectDir)\Resources\ProjDir.txt"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>`